# Is one permitted to face another direction besides towards eretz yisroel when praying?

Tags: tefilla, hashkafah-philosophy, halacha-theory

Assuming one isn't davening in a minyan so as not to disrespect the minyan but if someone is already praying on their own is it permissible to face another direction?

"Rebbe Yitzhak said: one who wish to become knowledgeable should face south during his prayers; and one who wishes to become wealthy should face north."

Comment: The commentaries explain that to mean one should angle themselves *slightly* north or south, but primarily they should still face Eretz Yisroel.

Comment: IIRC, if facing Eretz Yisroel has some problem (eg a picture or mirror in line of sight) another direction is ok and one should imagine one is facing the kodesh kodoshim. Agree with @N.T.